# Connecting individual road segments that participate in a dead end

Tags: arcgis-desktop, geoprocessing

I am trying to get a road feature class ready to do some analysis, regarding dead end roads. I have a road dataset cleaned up with continuous single segments, split at each road intersection. I have also added a field [DEADEND] noting any segment that dead ends (created through dangle topology). I have also identified any road segment that connect a dead end dangle with a non-dead end road (roads that have intersections on both ends). For example, a road that connects to multiple branching dead ends at one end and a non-dead end on the other, which would not be identified as a dangle in topology (as it has a vertex on each end, but is still part of a dead end).

If I query out the the segments ([DEADEND]="YES"), how do I merge the connected dead ends(sharing vertices) into individual continuous lines.

See picture for example.
[image]
I would like all segments labeled in green or purple into one line feature, without using the merge tool in the editor toolbar.

Comment: I tried using the dissolve geoprocess, but no matter what combination of outputs I tried, nothing resulted in the result I am looking for. It always resulted in either one multipart polyline containing all dead end roads (which explode back into individual segments) or the same individual segments I started with. I tried all options (multipart/unsplit check boxes on both dissolving on the [DEADEND] field and dissolving based on no field.

Comment: Not really sure about that but I think using Strahler stream order (https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/how-stream-order-works.htm) could help as your line with dangle will get an order of 1, your dead end connector should get an order of 2 and other road should get order of 3 or more... With Arcgis it seem you need spatial analyst and a raster steep to get it working

Comment: I'd say dissolve on yes, multipart ok and do multipart to single part. If only 2 dead lines share vertex, they'll become single line.